# Make Python code faster

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to make this code run faster?

```
a,b=map(int,input().split())
c=list(map(int,input().split()))
d=list(map(int,input().split()))
e=list(map(int,input().split()))

happy=0

for i in c:
    if i in d:
        happy=happy+1
    elif i in e:
        happy=happy-1

print(happy)
```

The code has to increment or decrement `happy` variable depending on if elements of `c` list are present in `d` or `e` lists. This code runs fine for small number of elements in `c`, `d` and `e` lists. But when there are many elements , the code execution is terminated due to timeout.

What can I do to make it run faster?

Comment: You could use sets instead of lists

Comment: There is no need to convert your inputs into integers. You can compare strings, the result will not change.

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid the loop. 
The variable `happy` is essentially the difference between the number of elements found in `d` and the number of elements found in `e`.

Could there be duplicates in `c`?

If you want to count the same element only once, then you can use `set`, that implicitly remove duplicates:

```
set_c = set(c)
happy_match = set_c.intersect(d)
unhappy_match = set_c.intersect(e)

happy = len(happy) - len(unhappy_match)
```

If you want to count each occurrence (including duplicates), then you can apply the same logic to lists:

```
happy_match = sum(1 if el in d else 0 for el in c)
unhappy_match = sum(1 if el in e else 0 for el in c)

happy = len(happy) - len(unhappy_match)
```

Comment: You can pass the lists `d` and `e` directly to `intersection`.